# work around Ruby's broken URI.parse, follow redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty, rest-client, faraday

I am using Ruby to scrape webpages that sometimes return redirects which I want to follow.
There is many Ruby gems that do that, but there is a problem:

Ruby's `URI.parse` explodes on some URIs that are technically invalid but work in browsers like `"http://www.google.com/?q=<>"`

```
URI.parse("http://www.google.com/?q=<>")               #=> error

require 'addressable/uri'
Addressable::URI.parse("http://www.google.com/?q=<>")  #=> works
```

All the HTTP client libraries I have tried (HttParty, Faraday, RestClient) break when they encounter such a URI in a redirect (this is on ruby 1.9.3)

#### rest-client:

```
require 'rest-client'
RestClient.get("http://bitly.com/ReeuYv") #=> explodes
```

#### faraday:

```
require 'faraday'
require 'faraday_middleware'
Faraday.use(FaradayMiddleware::FollowRedirects)
Faraday.get("http://bitly.com/ReeuYv")    #=> explodes
```

#### httparty:

```
require 'httparty'
HTTParty.get("http://bitly.com/ReeuYv")   # => explodes
```

#### open-uri:

```
require 'open-uri'
open("http://bitly.com/ReeuYv")           # => explodes
```

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: For what it's worth, `URI.parse` is actually just conforming to [RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-13) in this case - `<` and `>` should be URL-encoded. Browsers are simply more forgiving.

Comment: The assumption that a URI containing raw `<>` is valid is incorrect.

Comment: okay. but still, It would be nice if this worked. (corrected the question)

Comment: A simple http gem that is as forgiving as a browser's address bar would be a good thing to exist - there are numerous situations where it's valid for url handling to match what people are used to in their day to day web usage.

Answer (score 3):

Mechanize is my favourite web scraping gem.

> The Mechanize library is used for automating interaction with
>   websites. Mechanize automatically stores and sends cookies, follows
>   redirects, and can follow links and submit forms. Form fields can be
>   populated and submitted. Mechanize also keeps track of the sites that
>   you have visited as a history.

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://bitly.com/ReeuYv')
puts page.uri.to_s
=> http://www.google.com/?q=%3C%3E
```

It uses nokogiri to parse the html so every `Mechanize::Page` object can be treated like a nokogiri object so you can get bits of the html like

```
puts page.form('f').q
=> <>
```

The last part might seem like black magic but you really need to try `pp page` yourself. It makes the HTML so easy to scrape.

[Here](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_rdoc.html)'s a guide to get started with and the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

[Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) works:

```
require 'typhoeus'
Typhoeus::VERSION #=> "0.5.0.rc" 
Typhoeus.get("http://bitly.com/ReeuYv", followlocation: true).body
```

Answer (score 1):

[Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) seems to work:

```
require 'curb'
Curl.get("http://bitly.com/ReeuYv") { |c| 
  c.follow_location = true 
}.body_str  #=>  works
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
uri = URI.escape "http://www.google.com/?q=<>"


#=> "http://www.google.com/?q=%3C%3E"


URI.parse(uri) #=> no error
```

Comment: Yes. But I don't get to escape the URI because it is returned in a 302 response from some other server and handled deep inside whichever HTTP library I am using. (see the examples in the question, `http://bitly.com/ReeuYv` is a working uri that demonstrates the problem)